What is a quantum condensed space?
Due to a categorical equivalence involving compact topological spaces and unital commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras, there is a practise involved in so-called quantum mathematics where a noncommutative unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A$ is viewed as the algebra of continuous functions $A=C(\mathbb{X})$ on a so-called virtual object $\mathbb{X}$ which is said to be a compact quantum space.
Is there an analogous category of commutative algebras of functions for condensed sets (that the condensed space can be recovered from the commutative algebra of functions on it?)
The title question then asks: if there is such a category of commutative algebras, does it sit inside a category of noncommutative such algebras? Is there a Gelfand Duality around.
(This question is coming from pure idle curiosity)

I Googled this question but only just thought to Google 'Gelfand duality for condensed spaces' and this question is a duplicate.... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443059/noncommutative-condensed-sets
